# Product is not added to checkout cart

Tags: cart, addtocart

If someone click add to cart in list view all is fine:
https://www.gruen-im-kraut.de/hochbeete-krauterspiralen/kraeuterspiralen.html

If someone click add to cart on detail page the product is not added to the cart:https://www.gruen-im-kraut.de/kraeuterspirale-komplett-set-110.html

This is shown in the var/log

```
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' element cannot be added as child to 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
```

Any idea why?

---

This is shown in the var/log

[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' element cannot be added as child to 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-02-21 10:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions' and '' respectively. [] []

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't a form key, please add it in your template like this

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

or

```
<div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /></div>
```

**EDIT:**

I don't know if you just added it because I haven't seen it befor, it seems to me that you have an error in `js` trying to change `$` by `jQuery` or use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: this is shown in the frontend code input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="PpqD1YtoVQICibzB" /> This must be the form key? Its the luma theme used

Comment: Look my edit please